# Return count of ids where occurrence is equal to 1 in SQL

Tags: sql, group-by, count, having-clause

I have a dataset with a column of ids (e.g.)

```
ID
1
2
3
3
3
4
4
5
```

I want to return the count of the rows where an id only appears once. For example, from the above table the query would return count = 3 as only ID 1, 2 and 5 appear once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query:

```
SELECT id
FROM tablename
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

returns all the `id`s that you want to count, so count them like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
  SELECT id
  FROM tablename
  GROUP BY id
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
) t
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=b5bee7a327dde1bfae348541b4c19ac4).

Answer (score 0):

One method is two levels of aggregation

```
select count(*)
from (select id, count(*) as cnt
      from t
      group by id
     ) i
where cnt = 1;
```